# Bezier curves not rendering like preview

Tags: rendering, bezier-curves

[image: I'm having trouble getting the bezier curve to be smooth when rendering, but it looks fine on preview. Help!]

I'm having trouble getting the  bezier curve to be smooth when rendering, but it looks fine on preview. Help!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You have a high resolution preview and a low resolution render. Suggest you turn that around :)

p.s. welcome to BSE!

Comment: It worked, success! Thank you so much Patdog! And thanks for the warm welcome ;)